# Does Stripe JS have a call to create a file using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, .net, typescript, stripe-payments

Looking at the [Stripe API doc](https://stripe.com/docs/api/files/create) I can see that creating a file in .Net, Node, Java, PHP, etc, etc. is available, but I want to create a file id on the client side using Javascript/Typescript.

**QUESTION** - Is this possible, or do I have to post to my server to call the [.Net code](https://stripe.com/docs/api/files/create?lang=dotnet) to get a file id?
I don't see it anywhere in the documentation for either Stripe API or Stripe JS.

I do see the [Node.js code](https://stripe.com/docs/api/files/create), which I cold probably use, but I'm not sure what the
"fs" below means. Also, I'm not sure if this is cross compatible for Angular(typescript) which is what I'm using to create identity documents (license photo, passport photo) for my Connect accounts.

```js
const Stripe = require('stripe');
const stripe = Stripe('sk_test_something');
var fp = fs.readFileSync('/path/to/a/file.jpg');
var file = await stripe.files.create({
  purpose: 'identity_document',
  file: {
    data: fp,
    name: 'file.jpg',
    type: 'application/octet-stream',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically File Upload API uses a secret key, and you will need to call it from your server.
The “fs” is Node.js file system API, and you won’t be able to call it from Angular.

Now from client with your publishable key, you *can* actually call the File Upload API as the doc outlined:
https://stripe.com/docs/file-upload#using-your-publishable-key
But you will need to fetch an URL directly instead of using stripe.js. Here is an example:

```js
var pk = "pk_test_xxx"; // Your Publishable key

function init() {

  const uploadBtn = document.getElementById('btn-upload');
  uploadBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    uploadFile()
  });

}

function uploadFile() {
  console.log('uploadFile!');
  const fileInput = document.querySelector('#input-file-upload');
  const formData = new FormData();

  formData.append('file', fileInput.files[0]);
  formData.append('purpose', 'dispute_evidence');

  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${pk}`
    }
  };

  fetch('https://files.stripe.com/v1/files', options);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <hr>
    <section>
      <h3>
        File Upload Demo
      </h3>
      <input type="file" id="input-file-upload" name="file" />
      <button id="btn-upload">Upload file</button>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Orakaro for the help. Once I upload the file using the code you provided, is there any way to get the generated file upload id back from Stripe? Does the code you provide return anything? My objective is to get the file upload id so I can add it to the other parts of the customers connect account data when I create the account token.